# How does React enable importing SVG files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, import

When using React I can import SVGs as Wrapped as ReactComponents :

```
import { ReactComponent as Foo } from "./foo.svg";
```

and then use it anywhere I want to display the svg:

```
<Foo fill="orange"/>
```

But how does this work under the hood?

I see that React defines this module, providing a type of ReactComponent using SVGProps:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<
    SVGSVGElement
  > & { title?: string }>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

But where is the logic that actually maps the content of the file into the react component?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or something else to bootstrap your project?

Comment: @vr. yes I am using create-react-app